# estimate gas usage for a contract

Tags: gas, nft, gas-limit, gas-estimate, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to estimate the gas usage for a smart contract for an NFT token - is it possible to do before the actual sale?

contract is already published and all functions as well.

so I want to know how much contract will be used for the mint function of a smart contract

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the transaction with `estimateGas`. It basically runs the transaction locally, without sending it to the blockchain, and sees how much it costs. Check your library for the exact function name.

Although this functionality fails if the contract reverts (for example because the sale is not open yet). In that case you should deploy it locally, enable the sale functionality and do the same estimation - or even a real transaction.

Comment: is there no way to try and do that without deploying locally? seems like a ton of work just for gas calculation? - sale is not open yet

Comment: You can just fork mainnet and try locally